# Weird behavior of Interface

Tags: typescript

Here's a simple example confused me:

```
interface Test {
  key1: string;
  'attr.innerKey': string
}

const test: Test = {
  key1: 'I am a key',
  'attr.innerKey': 'innerKey'
}

test.key2 = 'I am key 2'; // here comes an error for there's no key2 in test
test['attr.innerKey2'] = 'error'; // Some how this works
```

It is so weird this line of code `test['attr.innerKey2'] = 'error';` passed.

Is it a bug or some special feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the default compiler behavior. By default, to ease migration from JS and to also not to break existing code, typescript has most of its stricter features disabled.

As such, dynamic access to keys (using `[]`) always succeeds even if the compiler knows that the types would suggest that it should fail, and the result of this index access is `any`. Static access (ie `.`)  is checked against the type and fails on inexistent properties. This was done as people usually use `.` for regular access but `[]` for when they want to access keys dynamically.

You can  tell the compiler you want it to check `[]` access as well if you use the `noImplicitAny` compiler option (although if you are starting a new project I would recommend using `strict` and disabling what you find particularly annoying, or better disable nothing).

The `noImplictAny` option will surface a lot of other errors,  such as missing parameter types, so enabling it on an existing code base is usually a bit painful (it is the single biggest hurdle when converting JS to TS in my experience) but the results are well worth it.